# Accidentally deleted my controllers folder in MVC 4 Web Application, how can I bring it back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Title is pretty self explanatory.  I want to bring back my controllers folder that was deleted so I can add a controller.  When I just make a new folder named "Controllers" the Add Controller option is not there.

I'm using VS2013 by the way.

Thank you

Comment: When I delete and re-add the Controllers folder everything works fine.

Comment: How do you add your folder? Do you created directly in Windows or using Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm right-clicking the Application in VS and clicking Add- New Folder.

Comment: If you are connected to any source control, you can pull it from there.

Comment: It should just work. If not, try unloading and reloading your project, or just restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can goto Menu->Project->Show All files.
You can see your deleted folder there. Just right click over it and "Include it in Project".

Answer (score 0):

Check your Recycle bin and Restore the file which you want.